# Scraping Table Data from Multiple Pages

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I think this is going to be complex...hoping someone is up for a challenge.

Basically, I'm trying to visit all HREF tags on a specific URL and then print their "profile-box" class into a Google Sheet.

I have a **working** example with a **different** link below. This code goes to each of the URLs, visits the Player Link, and then returns their associated data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1DpasSS8yC1UX6WqAbkQ515BwEEjdDL-x74T0eTW8hLM')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(3)
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url}

        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
            try:
                key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2019',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2018',
]


res = []
for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)
    res = [*res, *data]

if res != []:
    header = list(res[0].keys())
    values = [
        header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res]]
    worksheet.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

RESULTS OF THIS CODE (CORRECT):

[image: G League Profile boxes]

Secondarily - I have a **working** code that takes a separate URL, loops through 66 pages, and returns the table data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc'
res = []

for count in range(1, 66):
    # pd.read_html accepts a URL too so no need to make a separate request
    df_list = pd.read_html(f"{url}/{count}")
    res.append(df_list[-1])

pd.concat(res).to_csv('my data.csv')
```

This returns the table data from the URL and works perfectly:

[image: International Stats]

So... this brings me to my current issue:

I'm trying to take this same link (https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc)
and repeat the same action as the first code.

Meaning, I want to visit each profile (on all 66 or x number of pages), and print the profile data just like in the first code.

I thought/hoped, I'd be able to just replace the original D League URLS with this URL and it would work - it doesn't.  I'm a little confused why, because the table data seems to be the same set up?

I started trying to re-work this, but struggling.  I have very basic code, but think I'm taking steps backwards:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    profile_url = link.get("href")
    profile_response = requests.get(profile_url)
    profile_soup = BeautifulSoup(profile_response.text, "html.parser")
    profile_box = profile_soup.find("div", class_="profileBox")
    if profile_box:
        print(profile_box)
```

Any thoughts on this? Like I said, ultimately trying to recreate the same action as the first script, just for the 2nd URL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually largely use the same code that you used in your first example, with a slight modification to the first `find_all` loop.  Instead of using a `findall` you can use a `css` `selector` to select all of the table cells that have the `nowrap` class then test if that cell has a decendant link, and then from there the rest of your function should work the same as before.

Here is an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links2(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.select('td.nowrap'):
        a_tag = td.a
        if a_tag:
            name = a_tag.text
            player_url = a_tag['href']
            print(f"Getting {name}")

            req_player_url = requests.get(
                f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
            soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
            div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
            row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url}

            for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
                try:
                    key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                    row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
                except:     # not all entries have values
                    pass

            data.append(row)

    return data


urls2 = ["https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc"]

res2 = []
for url in urls2:
    data=get_links2(url)
    res2 = [*res2, *data]

print(res2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'Name': 'Jaroslaw Zyskowski', 'URL': '/player/Jaroslaw-Zyskowski/Summary/32427', 'Current Team': 'Trefl Sopot', 'Born': 'Jul 16, 1992(30 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Wroclaw, Poland', 'Natio
nality': 'Poland', 'Height': '6-7 (201cm)Weight:220 (100kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Manuel Capicchioni', 'Draft Entry': '2014 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', '
Pre-Draft Team': 'Kotwica Kolobrzeg (Poland)'}, {'Name': 'Ferdinand Zylka', 'URL': '/player/Ferdinand-Zylka/Summary/76159', 'Full Name': 'Ferdinand Leontin Zylka', 'Current Team': 'Basic-Fit Brussels
Basketball', 'Born': 'Apr 11, 1998(24 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Berlin, Germany', 'Nationality': 'Germany', 'Height': '6-3 (191cm)Weight:170 (77kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Fre
e Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2020 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Mitteldeutscher BC (Germany)'}, {'Name': 'Dainius Zvinklys', 'URL': '/player/Dainius-Zvinklys/Summary/151962', 'Cu
rrent Team': 'BBG Herford', 'Born': 'Nov 27, 1990(32 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Kretniga, Lithuania', 'Nationality': 'Lithuania', 'Height': '6-8 (203cm)Weight:187 (85kg)', 'Current NBA Statu
s': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2012 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Markuss Zvinis', 'URL': '/player/Markuss-Zvinis/Summary/183480', 'Current Team': 'BK Valmiera', 'Born
': 'Apr 26, 2005(17 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Latvia', 'Height': '6-4 (193cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Draft Eligible in 2027', 'Draft Entry': '2027 NBA Draft'}, {'Name': 'Ivars Zvigrus',
 'URL': '/player/Ivars-Zvigrus/Summary/204634', 'Current Team': 'Flyyingen BBK', 'Born': 'Oct 17, 1995(27 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Riga, Latvia', 'Nationality': 'Latvia', 'Height': '6-7 (2
01cm)Weight:204 (93kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2017 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Nikita Zverev', 'URL': '/player/Nikita-Zverev/Summary/3279
1', 'Current Team': 'Samara', 'Born': 'Apr 6, 1994(28 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Russia', 'Height': '6-10 (208cm)Weight:225 (102kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry':
'2016 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Khimki BC U18 (Russia)'}, {'Name': 'Fernando Zurbriggen', 'URL': '/player/Fernando-Zurbriggen/Summary/76271', 'Full Name': 'Fernando Zurbri
ggen', 'Current Team': 'Monbus Obradoiro', 'Born': 'Oct 20, 1997(25 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Santa Fe, Argentina', 'Nationality': 'Argentina', 'Height': '6-1 (185cm)Weight:190 (86kg)', 'Cu
rrent NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Franisco Javier Martin', 'Draft Entry': '2019 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Obras Sanitarias (Argentina)'}, {'Name': 'A
lejandro Zurbriggen', 'URL': '/player/Alejandro-Zurbriggen/Summary/42671', 'Current Team': 'Sant Antoni Ibiza Feeling', 'Born': 'Mar 18, 1995(27 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Santa Fe, Argentin
a', 'Nationality': 'Argentina', 'Height': '6-5 (196cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Franisco Javier Martin', 'Draft Entry': '2017 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undr
afted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Regatas Corrientes (Argentina)'}, {'Name': 'Nejc Zupan', 'URL': '/player/Nejc-Zupan/Summary/41700', 'Current Team': 'KK Tajfun Sentjur', 'Born': 'Apr 12, 1996(26 years old)'
, 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Koper, Slovenia', 'Nationality': 'Slovenia', 'Height': '6-8 (203cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Sead Galijasevic', 'Draft Entry': '
2018 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Sixt Primorska (Slovenia)'}, {'Name': 'Zhennian Zuo', 'URL': '/player/Zhennian-Zuo/Summary/92765', 'Current Team': 'Sichuan Blue Whales', 'B
orn': 'Jan 26, 1996(27 years old)', 'Nationality': 'China', 'Height': '6-8 (203cm)Weight:215 (98kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2018 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undr
afted'}, {'Name': 'Matija Zunic', 'URL': '/player/Matija-Zunic/Summary/156440', 'Current Team': 'HKK Zrinjski', 'Born': 'Jun 7, 1996(26 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Serbia', 'Height': '6-4 (193cm)Weig
ht:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2018 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Kyle Zunic', 'URL': '/player/Kyle-Zunic/Summary/107186', 'Current Team': '
Perth', 'Born': 'Mar 4, 1999(23 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Wollongong, Australia', 'Nationality': 'Australia', 'Height': '6-2 (188cm)Weight:195 (88kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted F
ree Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2022 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'High School': 'Lake Ginniderra High School[Burnie, Tasmania (Australia)]'}, {'Name': 'Karlis Zunda', 'URL': '/player/Karlis-Zunda/
Summary/123596', 'Current Team': 'Betsafe/Liepaja', 'Born': 'Aug 28, 1997(25 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Latvia', 'Height': '6-6 (198cm)Weight:187 (85kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Ag
ent', 'Draft Entry': '2019 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Zhang Zuming', 'URL': '/player/Zhang-Zuming/Summary/83723', 'Current Team': 'Qingdao', 'Born': 'Jan 27, 1995(28 years old)', '
Nationality': 'China', 'Height': '6-9 (206cm)Weight:198 (90kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2017 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Ningbo Roc
kets (China)'}, {'Name': 'Otoniel Zulueta', 'URL': '/player/Otoniel-Zulueta/Summary/184006', 'Current Team': 'N/A', 'Nationality': 'Mexico', 'Height': '6-6 (198cm)Weight:205 (93kg)', 'Current NBA Stat
us': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2019 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Nathan Zulemie', 'URL': '/player/Nathan-Zulemie/Summary/175816', 'Current Team': 'Espoirs Nanterre',
 'Born': 'Sep 7, 2004(18 years old)', 'Nationality': 'France', 'Height': '5-8 (173cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Draft Eligible in 2026', 'Draft Entry': '2026 NBA Draft'}, {'Name': 'Mantvydas
Zukauskas', 'URL': '/player/Mantvydas-Zukauskas/Summary/75749', 'Current Team': 'Vilkaviskio Perlas', 'Born': 'Oct 19, 1998(24 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Kaunas, Lithuania', 'Nationality': '
Lithuania', 'Height': '6-3 (191cm)Weight:185 (84kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2020 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Delikatesas Joniskis
(Lithuania)'}, {'Name': 'Eigirdas Zukauskas', 'URL': '/player/Eigirdas-Zukauskas/Summary/43242', 'Current Team': 'BC Wolves', 'Born': 'Jun 3, 1992(30 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Radviliskis,
Lithuania', 'Nationality': 'Lithuania', 'Height': '6-6 (198cm)Weight:190 (86kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2014 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft T
eam': 'Siauliai (Lithuania)'}, {'Name': 'Ivo Zukanovic', 'URL': '/player/Ivo-Zukanovic/Summary/171804', 'Current Team': 'KK Alkar', 'Born': 'Sep 1, 2002(20 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Croatia', 'Heig
ht': '6-3 (191cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Draft Eligible in 2024', 'Draft Entry': '2024 NBA Draft'}, {'Name': 'Kjeld Zuidema', 'URL': '/player/Kjeld-Zuidema/Summary/168658', 'Current Team':
 'Donar Groningen', 'Born': 'Jun 21, 2001(21 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Eexterzandvoort, Netherlands', 'Nationality': 'Netherlands', 'Height': '6-5 (196cm)Weight:198 (90kg)', 'Current NBA St
atus': 'Draft Eligible in 2023', 'Draft Entry': '2023 NBA Draft'}, {'Name': 'Ruben Zugno', 'URL': '/player/Ruben-Zugno/Summary/78457', 'Current Team': 'Zeus Energy Group Rieti', 'Born': 'Mar 20, 1996(
26 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Cantu, Italy', 'Nationality': 'Italy', 'Height': '6-1 (185cm)Weight:182 (83kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2018 NBA Draft
', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Acqua San Bernardo Cantu (Italy)'}, {'Name': 'Luka Zugic', 'URL': '/player/Luka-Zugic/Summary/172582', 'Current Team': 'KK Milenijum Podgorica', 'Born': '
Nov 22, 2000(22 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Podgorica, Montenegro', 'Nationality': 'Montenegro', 'Height': '6-5 (196cm)Weight:210 (95kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Dr
aft Entry': '2022 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Fedor Zugic', 'URL': '/player/Fedor-Zugic/Summary/128532', 'Current Team': 'Ratiopharm Ulm', 'Born': 'Sep 18, 2003(19 years old)', 'Bir
thplace/Hometown': 'Kotor, Montenegro', 'Nationality': 'Montenegro', 'Height': '6-6 (198cm)Weight:188 (85kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Draft Eligible in 2025', 'Agent': 'Rade Filipovich,David Mondress'
, 'Draft Entry': '2025 NBA Draft', 'Early Entry Info': '2022 Early Entrant(Withdrew)', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Ratiopharm Ulm (Germany)'}, {'Name': 'Andrey Zubkov', 'URL': '/player/Andrey-Zubkov/Summary/25
944', 'Current Team': 'Zenit Saint Petersburg', 'Born': 'Jun 29, 1991(31 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Chelyabinsk, Russia', 'Nationality': 'Russia', 'Height': '6-9 (206cm)Weight:195 (88kg)', '
Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Obrad Fimic', 'Draft Entry': '2013 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Lokomotiv Kuban (Russia)'}, {'Name': 'Aleksandr Zubk
ov', 'URL': '/player/Aleksandr-Zubkov/Summary/183206', 'Current Team': 'Runa-2', 'Born': 'Apr 7, 2002(20 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Russia', 'Height': '5-11 (180cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status':
 'Draft Eligible in 2024', 'Draft Entry': '2024 NBA Draft'}, {'Name': 'Aitor Zubizarreta', 'URL': '/player/Aitor-Zubizarreta/Summary/39787', 'Current Team': 'Acunsa GBC', 'Born': 'Mar 6, 1995(27 years
 old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Azpeitia, Spain', 'Nationality': 'Spain', 'Height': '6-4 (193cm)Weight:195 (88kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2017 NBA Draft', 'D
rafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'College of Idaho (Sr)'}, {'Name': 'Tomislav Zubcic', 'URL': '/player/Tomislav-Zubcic/Summary/2427', 'Current Team': 'London Lions', 'Born': 'Jan 17, 1990(33 ye
ars old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Zadar, Croatia', 'Nationality': 'Croatia', 'Height': '6-10 (208cm)Weight:230 (104kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Bill Duffy', 'Draft
 Entry': '2012 NBA Draft', 'Early Entry Info': '2011 Early Entrant(Withdrew)', 'Drafted': 'Round 2, Pick 26, Toronto Raptors', 'Draft Rights Trade': 'TOR to OKC, Jun 30, 2015', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'KK C
ibona (Croatia)'}, {'Name': 'Jure Zubac', 'URL': '/player/Jure-Zubac/Summary/38326', 'Current Team': 'Belfius Mons-Hainaut', 'Born': 'Mar 15, 1995(27 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Mostar, Bosni
a and Herzegovina', 'Nationality': 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Height': '6-8 (203cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2017 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'
, 'Pre-Draft Team': 'BC Siroki (Bosnia and Herzegovina)'}, {'Name': 'Peter Zsiros', 'URL': '/player/Peter-Zsiros/Summary/98310', 'Current Team': 'Zalakeramia-ZTE KK', 'Born': 'Jun 22, 1994(28 years ol
d)', 'Nationality': 'Hungary', 'Height': '6-7 (201cm)Weight:198 (90kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2016 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Harun Zrno
', 'URL': '/player/Harun-Zrno/Summary/188930', 'Current Team': 'OKK Spars Sarajevo', 'Born': 'Mar 1, 2004(18 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Height': '6-6 (198cm)Weight:N/A', 'C
urrent NBA Status': 'Draft Eligible in 2026', 'Draft Entry': '2026 NBA Draft'}, {'Name': 'Evangelos Zougris', 'URL': '/player/Evangelos-Zougris/Summary/183106', 'Current Team': 'Peristeri BC', 'Born':
 'Oct 14, 2004(18 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Greece', 'Height': '6-8 (203cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Draft Eligible in 2026', 'Draft Entry': '2026 NBA Draft'}, {'Name': 'Vitaliy Zotov', '
URL': '/player/Vitaliy-Zotov/Summary/54539', 'Current Team': 'BC Budivelnik', 'Born': 'Mar 3, 1997(25 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Lozovaya, Ukraine', 'Nationality': 'Ukraine', 'Height': '6-2
(188cm)Weight:185 (84kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Misko Raznatovic', 'Draft Entry': '2019 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Jan Zorvan', 'URL': '/playe
r/Jan-Zorvan/Summary/108564', 'Current Team': 'MBK Lucenec', 'Born': 'Dec 22, 1995(27 years old)', 'Nationality': 'Slovakia', 'Height': '6-7 (201cm)Weight:208 (94kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestric
ted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2017 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted'}, {'Name': 'Kristers Zoriks', 'URL': '/player/Kristers-Zoriks/Summary/54343', 'Current Team': 'BC VEF Riga', 'Born': 'May 25, 1
998(24 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Dobele, Latvia', 'Nationality': 'Latvia', 'Height': '6-4 (193cm)Weight:190 (86kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2022 NB
A Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'BC VEF Riga (Latvia)', 'High School': 'New Hampton School[New Hampton, New Hampshire (United States)]'}, {'Name': 'Yovel Zoosman', 'URL': '/player/
Yovel-Zoosman/Summary/75937', 'Current Team': 'ALBA Berlin', 'Born': 'May 12, 1998(24 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Kfar Saba, Israel', 'Nationality': 'Israel', 'Height': '6-7 (201cm)Weight:198
 (90kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Andrew Vye,Guillermo Bermejo,Brian Jungreis,Nadav Mor', 'Draft Entry': '2019 NBA Draft', 'Early Entry Info': '2019 Early Entrant',
'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Maccabi FOX Tel Aviv (Israel)'}, {'Name': 'Marcell Zoltan Volgyi', 'URL': '/player/Marcell-Zoltan-Volgyi/Summary/93730', 'Current Team': 'Budapesti Honved Se
', 'Born': 'Apr 22, 1998(24 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Nagykanizsa, Hungary', 'Nationality': 'Hungary', 'Height': '6-6 (198cm)Weight:200 (91kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Age
nt', 'Draft Entry': '2020 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Zalakeramia-ZTE KK (Hungary)'}, {'Name': 'Przemyslaw Zolnierewicz', 'URL': '/player/Przemyslaw-Zolnierewicz/Summary/531
22', 'Current Team': 'Enea Zastal BC Zielona', 'Born': 'Jul 3, 1995(27 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Paslek, Poland', 'Nationality': 'Poland', 'Height': '6-4 (193cm)Weight:200 (91kg)', 'Current
 NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Rade Filipovich', 'Draft Entry': '2017 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Asseco Arka Gdynia (Poland)'}, {'Name': 'Laurent Raphae
l Zoccoletti', 'URL': '/player/Laurent-Raphael-Zoccoletti/Summary/95274', 'Current Team': 'SAM Basket Massagno', 'Born': 'Nov 17, 1999(23 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Wettingen, Switzerland',
'Nationality': 'Switzerland', 'Height': '6-7 (201cm)Weight:N/A', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Draft Entry': '2021 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'BBC Nyon (
Switzerland)'}, ....
```

Comment: This is amazing @Alexander thanks for a thorough explanation.  I have it running - I need to take it a step further and push to G Sheet, but think I can hopefully solve that. MUCH APPRECIATED